# Ajax Post from client side to server side to log errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I'm trying to create an ajax post function which can log the errors at run time and send them silently to the server side for

This is the Code that i gave to post the data from the client side page

```js
var isDebugging = false;
var logJsErrors = true;
alert('passed variable decleration');
function ErrorSetting(msg, file_loc, line_no) {
    alert('entered the error setting method');
    var e_msg = msg;
    var e_file = file_loc;
    var e_line = line_no;
    var error_d = "Error in file: " + file_loc +
        "\nline number:" + line_no +
        "\nMessage:" + msg;
    if (logJsErrors) {
        theData = "file=" + file_loc + "&line=" + line_no + "&err=" + msg;
        alert('passed logging errors');
        ajaxCtrl(
            function () {
                return true;
            }, "http://localhost:57410/ServerPage.aspx", theData
        );
        alert('passed the ajax post');
    }

    if (isDebugging)
        alert("Error Found !!!\n--------------\n" + error_d);

    return true;
        }
    window.onload = ErrorSetting;
```

This is the definition for Ajax post function

```js
var callInProgress = false;
var xmlHttp;
function ajaxCtrl(fnfragment,theUrl,theData){
 
 var bAsync = true;

 this.xmlHttp = XmlHttp.create();

 if(theUrl)
  var url = theUrl; 
 else{
  alert('Target URL is Empty');
  return false;
 }
 try {
  xmlHttp.open("POST", url,bAsync);
     callInProgress = true;
 }catch(e){
     callInProgress = false;
     return false;
 }
 if (bAsync) {
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange= function(){
   //alert(xmlHttp.readyState);
   switch (xmlHttp.readyState) {
    case 4:
     callInProgress = false;
     if(fnfragment){
      fnfragment();

      // Clean up so IE doesn't leak memory
      //delete xmlHttp.onreadystatechange;
      //xmlHttp = null;

     }
     break;
   }
   /* if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
    callInProgress = false;
    if(fnfragment){
     fnfragment();

     // Clean up so IE doesn't leak memory
     //delete xmlHttp.onreadystatechange;
     //xmlHttp = null;

    }
   } */
  }
 }

 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

 if(theData)
  theKeyValPair = theData;
 else
  theKeyValPair = "";

 try {
  callInProgress = true;
  xmlHttp.send(theKeyValPair);
 }
 catch (e) {
  callInProgress = false;
  alert("Could not contact Server at this Time. Please Try again Later");
  return false;
 }

 if (!bAsync) {
     done();
 }
}
```

This is the VB Script that i have tried to add to the server side to get the data from the client page

```js
IF (request.form("") && request.form("file")!="") THEN

        Set fcontent = Date+request.form("file")+"\t"+request.form("line")+"\t"+request.form("err")+"\r\n"
        MsgBox(fcontent);
        WriteToFilecustom(fcontent)
    END IF                
        function WriteToFilecustom(log)
 
        set filename = "Logs\errorlog.txt"
        Dim fso, fs,tfile,fo
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    IF (fso.FileExists(filename)) then
        const ForAppending =8
        Set tfile = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForAppending ,true)
        tfile.WriteLine(log)
        else
       
         Set fo=fso.GetFolder(".\Logs")
         Set tfile=fo.CreateTextFile(name,false)      
         tfile.WriteLine(log)
    END IF
         tfile.Close
         Set fo = Nothing
         Set fso = Nothing   
            
         end function
```

I don't understand where i am going wrong as my post method is calling the URL but i'm unable to post the data

Comment: Note tha classic asp pages have `.asp` extension not `.aspx`, that is used by `asp.net` pages

Comment: do you see the data being posted if you open up Dev Tools under the network tab?

Comment: Yes Ricardo they are indeed Asp.Net Pages because i'm using Visual studio 2017 i'm unable to understand how to run asp pages in it, so for the time being i am using Aspx pages to test

Comment: Yeah Josh in the network bar it is actually showing the post method being invoked but i have never tried this so i don't know the whole process about what happens at server side after the client posts the data, i just wanna know weather i.m going in the right direction or not

Comment: can any one please help me out with the server side logic